# RegExp - Replace exact String

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I need a help in regular expression, I am trying to replace "Inc" with "LLC" for many string.

I used this code in java :

```
String newValue = newValue.replaceAll("(?i)Inc[^\\w]","LLC");
```

But the result is incorrect, one char is removed after replacing :

Exp: CONSULTANTS, INC. ("ABC") ==>  CONSULTANTS, LLC ("ABC") // the "." was removed.

Please note that i have used [^\w] to prevent replacing "inc" in sentences like "include".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\b` for [word boundaries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) if there is no special literals in the string like `^` or `()`:

```
String s = "include inc".replaceAll("(?i)\\binc\\b", "LLC");
System.out.println(s); // (?i) is for case insensitive.
```

Above approach would fail if you use special characters in place of `inc` like `^inc`. You can use `Pattern.quote(s)` for it to work.

If there are special characters then you can use quoted literals `\Q...\E`. Utility method using quoted literals:

```
public static String replaceExact(String str, String from, String to) {
    return str.replaceAll("(?<!\\w)\\Q" + from + "\\E(?!\\w)", to);
}
```

Note: `Pattern.quote("wor^d")` will return `\\Qwor^d\\E` which is same as above regex.